# Is it possible to have a composite ng2-charts bar and line chart?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ng2-charts

I am using ng2-charts and require a composite bar and line chart. Is this possible?

Currently I can get bar and line charts working separately, my template looks like...

```
<div>
  <div style="display: block">

    <canvas baseChart
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
    <div align="center">{{barChartTitle}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you find this out ? I'm looking a way to do it also

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it in as part of the data object in the typescript, for example:

```
{
    data: [3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 4, 2, 2, 0], 
    label: '',
    type: 'bar'
}
```